# Jquery + input very awkward bug, simple > comparison not working

Tags: jquery, input, comparison-operators

Good day,

I am having a very but very frustrating bug.

```
function handle_max_amount() {
    var money = $('#AmountField').val();
    var open_amount = $('#total_open_amount').val();


    if (money < 0){
        $('#AmountField').val(0);
    }
    else if (open_amount < money) {
        $('#AmountField').val(open_amount);
    }
}
```

The following code is executed by a very simple piece of code

```
<input id="total_open_amount" type="hidden" value="137">
<input type="text" id="AmountField" onchange="handle_max_amount();" />
```

And this is absolute basic. I know but even if I enter 50 for example he resets it to 137. Because Javascript claims that 50 is larger than 137.

I have checked if I haven't double defined the ID fields.

But as well **total_open_amount** and **AmountField** have been defined once.

Since this is so terribly awkard I am asking this here.

Comment: You just need to use `parseInt()`!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse values to int type to compare, like below

```
function handle_max_amount() {
    var money = parseInt($('#AmountField').val() || "0");
    var open_amount = parseInt($('#total_open_amount').val() || "0");

    if (money < 0){
        $('#AmountField').val(0);
    }
    else if (open_amount < money) {
        $('#AmountField').val(open_amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `.val()` returns string, you can not use string value for comparison especially when you're doing any mathematical operations.

Use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) instead.

```js
function handle_max_amount() {
    var money = parseInt($('#AmountField').val());
    var open_amount = parseInt($('#total_open_amount').val());
    if (money < 0){
        $('#AmountField').val(0);
    }
    else if (open_amount < money) {
        $('#AmountField').val(open_amount);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="total_open_amount" type="hidden" value="137">
<input type="text" id="AmountField" onchange="handle_max_amount();" />
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

> As you are dealing with variables that stores money, you need to use
>   `parseFloat()` rather than `parseInt()`